# Script to open webpage and search

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write a PowerShell script to open up a window in chrome, go to google, enter text in the search bar, hit enter, and then retrieve all the links in an array. Here's my first attempt at the code:

```
$URI = "www.google.com"
$HTML = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $URI
$SearchField = $HTML.ParsedHtml.getElementById('lst-ib')
$SearchField.value = "green flowers"
$SearchButton = $HTML.ParsedHtml.getElementsByName('btnK')
$SearchButton.click();
//Grab links and store into array
```

But when I try to run it I get this:

```
The property 'value' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property
exists and can be set.
At line:4 char:1
+ $SearchField.value = "green flowers"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException

Method invocation failed because [System.DBNull] does not contain a method named
'click'.
At line:6 char:1
+ $SearchButton.click();
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

Comment: On the real site, do you need to do a get or a post?

Answer (score 0):

```
$Site = "www.google.com/search?q=green+flowers"
$Test = Invoke-WebRequest -URI $Site
$Test.Links | Foreach {$_.href }
```